# Object Oriented approach of Polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have been taught in my C++ OOP class about polymorphism that how we can provide virtual function interfaces to derived classes. But the question is how all this can help? Every time we make a base class pointer and store a derived class object in it, But why? Can't we do it just by function overriding. 
Please Tell a programming problem which cannot be solved except with polymorphism in C++

Answer (score 0):

#### Virtual functions and overriding vs. non-virtual functions and name hiding

Virtual functions make a class polymorphic.  A virtual function can be overriden in derived classes.  When you invoke that function through a base class pointer, it's always the function corresponding to the real dynamic type of the poined object that will be called. It's dynamic determination at run-time.

Non-virtual functions can't be overriden.  When a derived class has a non-virtual function with the same signature than the base class, it's two different functions but the name of the derived class hides the one of the base class.  When you invoke the function through a base class pointer, it's allways the function corresponding to the base class which will be invoked.  It's static determination at compile-time.

#### What's the benefit ? do we need virtual functions ?

Virtual functions are just an easy way to define abstraction.  The typical example are shapes.  You define an abstract shape, with a virtual  functions such as `calculateSurface()`.  You then can call that function via any pointer and you'll be sure that for any concrete shape (e.g. circle, square, hexagon...) it will always apply the right formula for the object.

Abstraction is convenient.  But you could live without it.  For example, you could as well implement the same functionality, by using a shape code, and having a a `calculateSurface()` that would execute the right formula depending on the shape code.  It's perfectly possible.  It's just more difficult to maintain, because everytime you create a new shape, you'd need to ad another `if (shapeCode==xx)` clause in all the places where the behavior is dependent of the shape.

In fact you don't even need an OOP.  In former times, before c++ existed, it was a common programming technique to use function pointers in C to emulate such a type dependent behavior (using a struct that contained a function pointer for every type dependent operation).  Again, it's perfectly feasible, but even more tedious and more error prone and less encapsulated.

So, there is no problel that would require polymorphism to be solved.  There are just plenty of problems where OOP and polymorphism makes the problem easier to solve, with more maintainable code.